# Cipher challenge

Tags: encryption, cryptography

So I was recently challenged by someone to solve this cipher. I am not entirely sure which section of the stack exchange this belongs but I **think** that this is ok for superuser.

Below is the cipher (which should result in a string). Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated!

```
75628 28591 62916 48164 91748 58464 74748 28483 81638 18174
74826 26475 83828 49175 74658 37575 75936 36565 81638 17585
75756 46282 92857 46382 75748 38165 81848 56485 64858 56382
72628 36281 81728 16463 75828 16483 63828 58163 63630 47481
91918 46385 84656 48565 62946 26285 91859 17491 72756 46575
71658 36264 74818 28462 82649 18193 65626 48484 91838 57491
81657 27483 83858 28364 62726 26562 83759 27263 82827 27283
82858 47582 81837 28462 82837 58164 75748 58162 92000
```

Comment: Voted to close as it is outside of scope for SU (its not about hardware or software).  I don't see a way to transfer it - and Indeed I don't even know if its suitable - but http://crypto.stackexchange.com/ would seem an appropriate location.

Comment: @davidgo Crypto.SE considers "decipher/analyze this block of data" to be off-topic (the answers don't really help anyone else; it's a special case of the old "too localized" close reason). This question wouldn't go there, or on Sec.SE (for the same reason). I don't think SE has anywhere for questions like this; it _might_ go on Puzzling, not sure about that site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an as-yet unbroken cipher that appears in the first edition of Codes and Ciphers, an elementary book on cryptography published by the Russian-born English cartographer Alexander D'Agapeyeff.

Please see this link:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Agapeyeff_cipher

Offered as a "challenge cipher" at the end of the book, it was not included in later editions, and D'Agapeyeff is said to have admitted later to having forgotten how he had encrypted it.

THIS CAN'T BE BROKED